# No log content with tail but when terminating a process I see content with less

Tags: linux, io-redirection, tail, nohup

Basically, I am running:

```
nohup ./executable &> /tmp/out.log &
```

In order to make sure the process is running I ran the command:

```
tail -f /tmp/out.log
```

But the only thing I can get from `tail` is "nohup: ignoring input", and once killing the process that previously started I can see the contents of `out.log`

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run your program as:

```
nohup stdbuf -oL ./executable &> /tmp/out.log &
```

stdbuf can change the default buffering.

Answer (score 4):

Your executable is using buffered output, so you will only see something with `tail` if more than one block of output is produced. The size of such a block will be 4k or more.

If you wrote the executable yourself, change the output to line buffered or to not buffered.

Comment: +1 Or add an instruction to flush stdout ; nonetheless we cannot give a better answer to such a vague question.

Comment: makes sense, the executable is from the LoRa device provider. Is there an easy workaround? thanks for the response!

Comment: You can allocate a pty and give that to the executable. Most programs use line buffered for a tty. Your program also does if you see immediate output if you run it directly from the shell.